# Reducer not changing state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Below are the relevant files.
In the reducer, when it runs...

```
 return {
   loggedIn: action.loggedIn
 };
```

I was expecting it to replace the state with that information.
When I run this code in LoginForm I get the old state output.

```
this.props.onLogin();
console.log(this.props.loggedIn);
```

I'm hoping I'm overlooking something simple here. Everything else seem to work the way I was expecting it to. I can change the state directly in the 
switch using...

state.loggedIn = action.loggedIn;

And it works as expected. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Action

```
import { LOGGED_IN } from './actionTypes';

export const loggedIn = () => {
    return {
        type: LOGGED_IN,
        loggedIn: true,
    };
};
```

Reducer

```
import {
  LOGGED_IN
} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGED_IN:
     return {
       loggedIn: action.loggedIn
     };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import firebase from '../Fire';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
  loggedIn
} from "../store/actions";
```

LoginForm 
    class LoginForm extends Component {

```
  onButtonPress() {
    this.onLoginSuccess();
  }

  onLoginSuccess() {
    this.props.onLogin();
    console.log(this.props.loggedIn);
    Actions.main({});
  }

  renderButton() {
    return (
      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
        Log in
      </Button>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            placeholder="user@gmail.com"
            label="Email"
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="password"
            label="Password"
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loggedIn: state.loggedIn
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onLogin: () => dispatch(loggedIn()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

configureStore

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import prolinkReducer from './reducers/prolink';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    loggedIn: prolinkReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
};

export default configureStore;
```

Comment: I am not a react/redux expert but I am wondering if the dispatch function is asynchronous, so you call the onLogin and immediately print the current state before it has been updated by the reducer. Try wrapping the console.log(this.props.loggedIn) in a setTimeout with a 100 milisecond delay and see if it prints the correct value you're expecting because that would indicate dispatch is an async call

Comment: Good idea, I will give that a try.

Comment: No luck trying this.

Comment: are you using multiple reducers? I mean combineReducers?

Comment: We are using 1 reducer with combineReducers.

Comment: I edited the question and added the configureStore code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the previous value is that you are console logging the previous value.

When the `onLoginSuccess` is called the current value for `this.props.loggedIn` will be passed to the `console.log`. I imagine if you set a long enough timeout on it then it would show that it is being updated, but that is not exactly the best way to check.

## componentDidUpdate

If you want to check that your redux state is updating you should check what is happening in the `componentDidUpdate` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

As you subscribe to `loggedIn` in your `mapStateToProps` in your `LoginForm.js`, that means your component will receive the new value for `loggedIn` once it is updated.

In your `LoginForm.js` add the following:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.warn('previous', prevProps.loggedIn, 'current', this.props.loggedIn)
}
```

This will allow you to see the values for `loggedIn` as it changes.

## react-native-debugger

You could use `react-native-debugger` which includes redux inspection tools. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger. This allows you to see your redux store in real-time, meaning you can easily track the changes without having to resort to checking in the `componentDidUpdate`. However, at this time there is currently an issue with `react-native-debugger` that means it is not working with `react-native 0.58.+`, though there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/pull/307) that fixes the issue.

## middleware

Alternatively you could add a middleware to your redux setup that logs each event to your console. https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware, I have previously used `redux-logger` it is quite customisable, and depending on your use cases you may find it suits your needs.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Great explanation!